# Using tortoiseSVN, how do you tag the code?

Tags: tortoisesvn

Using TortoiseSVN, how do you tag the code?

Is the process to branch exactly the same?

I know you have to just copy the code to the /tag/ folder, but how?

i.e. I want to copy revision # to a tag#.

Will it affect the /trunk/ at all?

Comment: Why didn't you accept one of these answers? If you get a correct answer the idea is to award it.

Answer (score 29):

The answers here were missing some key information for getting started with SVN and braches.

Step 1: You need to make sure you have a suitable branches/tags dir.  e.g. if your project has this structure:

```
url/myproj/trunk/...
```

you also need:

```
url/myproj/tags/
url/myproj/branches/
```

To do this, don't "add" the directories and commit them, or tortoise will give you an error.  Instead use the tortoise svn repo-browser, go to myproj then right click and "add Folder".

Step 2: Right click on your trunk folder, select "tortoise SVN" then "branch/tag".  The copy branch/tag dialogue now pops up.

Step 3: Set the "to Path" to "/myproj/tags/myversion" where myversion is usually something like "1.0".  Select "Head revision in the repository" and make sure "switch working to new branch/tag" is not checked.  Hit OK.

Step 4: Unfortunately, next time you do an update, it will pull down the branches and tags as files. This means your HD will get filled with every file from every branch and version created.    One solution is to only checkout each individual trunk dir, which is not always convenient (as you have to manually update 30 trunk dirs if you have one repo with 30 projects).

Personally, having used CVS, SCCS, PVCS, VSS & Rational for 30 years, I find SVN much harder to work with.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  This is the best answer in my opinion because it's very clear that one must launch the svn dialogue on the trunk folder, that it expects tags and branch folder etc...  some of other answers just say "enter you target url"... well as a novice, that's the whole reason I'm here.  What specificially should go there?

Thanks again

Answer (score 15):

1. Right click on your project folder and select Branch/Tag
2. Point the URL to whatever you want the folder to be called inside the /Tag/ folder
3. Select Specific revision in repository and choose the one you want

It won't affect the trunk at all.

Answer (score 8):

How to create a tag :

1. Right click on your repository local copy
2. Choose Create a branch or a tag...
3. Choose URL of the tag (normally at the same level that *trunk* you have a *tags* folder)
4. Choose which revision you want to tag 
   (Usually, you will choose HEAD revision. Why ? Because normally tags are to mark a state of your repository typically for release management, and then when you have the repository state wished, you tag it and then continue the development.

Yes, it's almost the same process that for *branches*, the difference is "conceptual".

No effect to your trunk !

Answer (score 7):

[Here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html)'s the official documentation.

Creating a tag won't affect the trunk nor your working copy (you'll still be pointing to trunk) unless you switch to the newly created tag or branch.

Answer (score 0):

Answers below:
   The process is almost exactly the same as a branch.
   A branch is a tag which is updated essentially.

Right click on the folder you want to tag, click on RepoBrowser, then branch/tag.
   Modify the ToURL, with where you want to place your tag
   Enter your comment/tag in the box below.
   This will tag the code in the folder, without moving it.

This will not effect the trunk at all.